# Using a matrix-vector-product to generate n amount of vectors in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector, series

I have 2x1 vector x1 and a 2x2 matrix P. I have to calculate x2=P*x1, x3=P*x2... etc. How do I get R to calculate an arbitrary xn of my choosing, for example x100?

Comment: In 2 lines: `xn <- x1; for(i in seq.int(n)[-1]) xn <- P %*% xn`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas. How to do a line break in comments?

Comment: The semi-colon separates instructions.